# Issue in Reading a file from gcs bucket through python script

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to open a csv file which is present in gcs bucket to read the content and process the data accordingly in BigQuery. I am able to list out the csv's present in bucket , but not able to open it . My code is as below:

```
with cloudstorage.open(bucket_name/gs_file,"r+") as csvFile:
     reader = csv.reader(iter(csvFile.readline,''), delimiter = '|')
     csvfilearray = next(reader)
     print (csvfilearray)
```

Getting below error :

> NameError: name 'cloudstorage' is not defined

Imported cloudstorage as below:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
```

and tried with `gcs.open` again , But still error :

```
File "./GCS_Connection_Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    import cloudstorage as gcs
ImportError: No module named cloudstorage
```

Can anyone please help on how to open a file present on GCS for processing .

Comment: Did you install the [`google-cloud-storage`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) lib?

Comment: Or, if you're on GAE, the [`appengine-gcs-client`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#downloading_the_client_library) lib which matches your import according to [Reading and Writing to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage)

Comment: executing the python code from google vm instance and I am able to fetch the object list under a particular bucket.So, seems google-cloud-storage lib is installed there.Not able to open the file for processing.   I have written below imports in code "from google.cloud import storage"
storage_client = storage.Client()

Comment: Tried with installing using    
"pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient " .still getting error as below : 
 import cloudstorage as gcs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudstorage/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .api_utils import RetryParams
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudstorage/api_utils.py", line 45, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import app_identity
ImportError: No module named appengine.api

Please help, what needs to be done to resolve it

Comment: Is this a GAE app or not? If it is, you need the 2nd lib, installed in your app (not on the system), otherwise you need the 1st lib, installed on the system. Not the other way around.

Comment: It is GAE app. I have tried with installing Library as below:

Comment: Then re-check the instructions, you need to install it into your app, i.e. note the `-t` arg in the `pip install ... -t lib` cmd. Your traceback clearly shows it's running the lib installed into your system's dist packages, which won't work on GAE.

Comment: It is GAE app. I have tried with installing Library as below:
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient 
I could not run "pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <your_app_directory/lib> " As i am not sure what is meant by <your_app_directory>
my Cloudstorage folder contains below files:
test_utils.py,storage_api.py,rest_api.py,__init__.py,errors.py,common.py,cloudstorage_api.py,api_utils.py,__init__.pyc,api_utils.pyc
cloudstorage_api.pyc,errors.pyc,common.pyc,rest_api.pyc,test_utils.pyc,storage_api.pyc

Could you please suggest further

Comment: Your [GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/) app code directory. Hm, what you showed doesn't quite look like a GAE app. what's your `app.yaml` file content?

Comment: cat app.yaml
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
#[START env]
env_variables:
    CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: your-bucket-name
#[END env]

Answer (score 1):

You're on the flexible environment according to your `app.yaml` file.

You used `GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient`, which is a standard environment library (just as `appengine-gcs-client`), you need to use the `google-cloud-storage` library, see [Edit project configuration and install dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage#edit_project_configuration_and_install_dependencies) section in the [Using Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage) guide, which is the one you need to follow.

You also followed the standard environment instructions for installing the library, you need to use the flexible environment ones, see [Using Python Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries).

General note: look for the `docs/flexible` vs `docs/standard` strings in the doc page URLs to distinguish them (or the environment type displayed close to the top of the documentation left-side navigation bar, you may need to scroll up to see it)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or/45842773#45842773

Comment: First of all, Thanks a lot for responding on my queries. I am new to Google Cloud and kind of lost in documentations and also tired now to find solution to this issue.I followed the link you suggested. Created virtual env too but still at same position. Can you please suggest whether the the cloudstorage import what I am using and Cloudstorage.open() function is Valid(will work )or not in a flexible environment ? is there any other way to open a csv from GCS bucket and process the file according to the requirement. This method looked simple to me but not getting any soultion for import issue.

Comment: No, the library you're using now won't work. Get some rest and then start fresh with the right documentation.